# Update Multiple Rows at Once in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display table of student in "Class 1". User can change the information and update it into database. I want to update multiple rows at a time, but it ends up updating only 1 row (the last row). Please help me .. how should i change the code in order to update multiple rows at once, when i click on update. Thanks.

This is the code:

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'test');

$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());
$database = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_set_charset("utf8", $connection);
?>

    <form action='update.php' method='post'>
    <table border='1'>
        <?php
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE class = 1 ");

                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td colspan='3'>CLASS 1</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."' /></td>";
                        echo "<td>name  :<input type='text' name='name' value='".$row['name']."' /></td>";
                        echo "<td>Sex  :<input type='text' name='sex' value='".$row['sex']."' /></td>";
                        echo "<td>Age  :<input type='text' name='age' value='".$row['age']."' /></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";

            }

            echo "<input type='submit' name='update' value='UPDATE' />";
        ?>
    <table>
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    $id  = $_POST['id'];
    $name= $_POST['name'];
    $sex = $_POST['sex'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];

    mysql_query("   UPDATE student
                       SET name= '$name', sex='$sex', age='$age'
                     WHERE id = '$id' ");   

    header("location: update.php");
    exit;
}   

?>
```

[image: form]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use input arrays. So your inputs should look like this instead (notice the name attribute):

```
echo "<td>Sex  :<input type='text' name='name[]' value='".$row['name']."' /></td>";
```

Then in PHP $_POST['name'] will be an array:

```
foreach($_POST['name'] as $name){
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 3):

You should create your sql dynamicly and execute the latest sql sentence. You can use a foreach loop to check all ids and simply append each update statement to a string variable. You can find an example here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImirOX73atc

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the code that handles the posted data into a loop, like

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    $i = 0;
    while(isset($_POST['row_'.$i.'_id')) {
      $row_id  = $_POST['row_'.$i.'_id'];
      echo $row_id;
      // do update sql
      $i++;
    }
  }
?>
```

and also change the following line:

```
<?php
  //Instead of
  //echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."' /></td>";
  echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='row_'.$i.'_id' value='".$row['id']."' /></td>";
?>
```

while also iterating $i in the while loop that you get the MySQL results in.

Or you can use post arrays as implied in another answer.