# save button that will save data in my local host table

Tags: php, mysql

Hi all I create some script using fetch array to display my result but now i'm having problem how will I insert data result in new table

---1st page

```
<?php
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"grouping\" value=\"".stripslashes('NINS_LEC')."\" /></td>";
echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"InvoiceAccNum\" value=\"". stripslashes($row['InvoiceAccNum'])  ."\" /> </td>";
 echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"AccountFirstName\" value=\"".    stripslashes($row['AccountFirstName']) . "\" /></td>";
 echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"SubsidiaryCode\" value=\"". stripslashes($row['SubsidiaryCode']) ."\" /></td>";
 echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"HandlingCode\" value=\"" . stripslashes($row['HandlingCode']) . "\" /></td>";
           echo "</tr>";
       }
    ?>
</table>
   <?echo "$num_rows Rows\n";?>
 <? echo 
"<form name='vw_ob_save' method='get'>
<fieldset>
<table width='680'><tr>
<td colspan='4' align='center'>
<input type='submit' name='btn_save' value='Save'>
</td></tr></table></fieldset></form>";
if(isset($_POST['btn_save'])){
include 'grouping.php';
if($query1>0){
msgalert("data save!");}
}?>
```

This one is working now but when my grouping.php page are execute i only have 1 data save in my table.

grouping.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $hostname = "localhost"; 

    //connection to the database
    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
    or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
    echo "";

    $selected = mysql_select_db("bsswebtool",$dbhandle)
    or die("Could not select bsswebtool");

    if(empty($_POST['form1']))
    {

$grouping                = $_POST['grouping'];
$InvoiceAccNum       = $_POST['InvoiceAccNum'];
$AccountFirstName        = $_POST['AccountFirstName'];
$SubsidiaryCode       = $_POST['SubsidiaryCode'];
$HandlingCode           = $_POST['HandlingCode'];
    }
    else
    {

    $grouping                =null;
$InvoiceAccNum           =null;
$AccountFirstName        =null;
$SubsidiaryCode          =null;
$HandlingCode            =null;
}

 $query1 = "INSERT INTO nins_lec (rid,grouping,InvoiceAccNum,AccountFirstName,SubsidiaryCode,HandlingCode)
 values 
        ('','$grouping','$InvoiceAccNum','$AccountFirstName','$SubsidiaryCode','$HandlingCode')";

mysql_query($query1);

   ?>
```

I expect 9 rows affected in my database but only 1 row are inserted upon checking in my DB
example data result

```
   Groupings InvoiceAccNum  AccountFirstName       SubsidiaryCode   HandlingCode
  NINS_LEC    0000000000    ana                             XXXX        D
  NINS_LEC    0000000000    tiana                           XXXX        Q
  NINS_LEC    0000000000    LOPEZ KARL CHU                  XXXX        Q
  NINS_LEC    0000000000    pepe                            XXXX        Q
  NINS_LEC    0000000000    SANTOS                          XXXX        R
  NINS_LEC    0000000000    WONG                            XXXX        Q 
  NINS_LEC    0000000000    BERNALDEZ                       XXXX        R
  NINS_LEC    0000000000    PALICOS                         XXXX        Q
  NINS_LEC    0000000000     JOSE                           XXXX        Q
  9 Rows
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910017/update-multiple-rows-at-once-in-php/18910109#18910109

Comment: nope this one is different, i have to save my result in my db but i only have one result save,

Comment: How is it different, since you are trying to do 1 INSERT query for 9 different values, without it being in a loop?

Comment: Ok, got it. You have 9 forms ... that could work, but not with always having the same form field e.g. `name="grouping"`. Either you put an id here like `name="grouping_3"` or use an array like `name="grouping[]"` (which is imho the better option). Also, you need a loop to do your SQL stuff than.

Comment: at the 1st page i already used select * query just to call that 9 result so i need to do now is to save that 9 result in different table..sorry if i cant explain it good..

Answer (score 0):

```
  <form name='vw_ob_save' method='get'>

  ...

   $_POST['grouping'];
```

When your form useses **get** then you cant access request via $_POST on your php scirpt!

Comment: ... so use `$_GET` instead ;) ... or change the forms method to `post`

Comment: I already change method to post but still data save in my db is 1 i have 9 result expected

Answer (score 0):

Is `rid` the main ID of the table (unique/primary key)? If so, remove it from the INSERT.
I corrected a missing comma below!

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO nins_lec (rid, grouping, InvoiceAccNum , AccountFirstName, Subsidiary, CodeHandlingCode)
values ('', '$grouping', '$InvoiceAccNum', '$AccountFirstName', '$SubsidiaryCode', '$HandlingCode')";
```

Comment: thanks djot, rid is not unique code for the table i just put rid so i have reference.